# Jest test a removable of a dom element

Tags: typescript, testing, jestjs

I have this fonction that removes an element from the dom

```
export function removeSlot(component: any, selector: string) {
  if (component.querySelectorAll(selector).length > 0) {
    component.querySelectorAll(selector).forEach(el => el.remove());
  } else {
    console.error(`'${selector}' not found in component '${component.tagName.toLowerCase()}'`);
  }
}
```

So far I have this code

```
describe('delete element', () => {
  it('delete the element', function() {
    const html = `
      <div>
        <ol>
          <li>
            <a href="https://www.example.com/">lorem</a>
          </li>
          <li>lorem</li>
          <li>
            <a href="https://www.example.com/">
              lorem
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>lorem</li>
        </ol>
      </div>
      `;
    document.body.innerHTML = html;

    removeSlot(html, 'ol');

    expect(document.querySelectorAll('ol').length).toEqual(1);
  });
});
```

I get errors

[image]

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the unit test solution:

`index.ts`:

```js
export function removeSlot(component: any, selector: string) {
  if (component.querySelectorAll(selector).length > 0) {
    component.querySelectorAll(selector).forEach((el) => el.remove());
  } else {
    console.error(`'${selector}' not found in component '${component.tagName.toLowerCase()}'`);
  }
}
```

`index.test.ts`:

```js
import { removeSlot } from './';

describe('59886364', () => {
  it('should remove each el', () => {
    const mNodeList = [{ remove: jest.fn() }];
    const mComponent = { querySelectorAll: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(mNodeList) };
    const mSelector = 'ol';
    removeSlot(mComponent, mSelector);
    expect(mComponent.querySelectorAll).toBeCalledTimes(2);
    expect(mComponent.querySelectorAll).toBeCalledWith(mSelector);
    mNodeList.forEach((el) => {
      expect(el.remove).toBeCalled();
    });
  });

  it('should print error if no node found', () => {
    jest.spyOn(console, 'error');
    const mNodeList = [];
    const mComponent = { tagName: 'DIV', querySelectorAll: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(mNodeList) };
    const mSelector = 'ol';
    removeSlot(mComponent, mSelector);
    expect(mComponent.querySelectorAll).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    expect(mComponent.querySelectorAll).toBeCalledWith(mSelector);
    expect(console.error).toBeCalledWith(`'ol' not found in component 'div'`);
  });
});
```

Unit test results with 100% coverage:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/59886364/index.test.ts
  59886364
    ✓ should remove each el (6ms)
    ✓ should print error if no node found (4ms)

  console.error node_modules/jest-mock/build/index.js:860
    'ol' not found in component 'div'

----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.ts |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        5.377s, estimated 15s
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/59886364